# Handle date in LONG format in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We have below code for "Date" in LONG format in one of the requests in Jmeter

SubmittedDate":{"value":1672986618263}

_CreatedDate":{"value":1672986618264}

Please help me to how to handle to get current date and time in Long format during replay or run time

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be the timestamp in milliseconds since the beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), in JMeter there is [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which returns current timestamp.

If you want the "CreatedDate" to be 1 millisecond larger than the `SubmittedDate` you can use [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum)

Something like:

```
SubmittedDate":{"value":${__time(,created)}}

_CreatedDate":{"value":${__longSum(${created},1,)}}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)